# Reference custom contact source when using ABPeoplePickerView (OS X)

Tags: addressbook, abpeoplepickerview

ABPeoplePickerView (OS X) does not appear to allow one to use a custom contact source, instead forced to reference the stock Address Book database. It appears that the corresponding framework in the IOS platform does allow a custom source.

Is this conclusion accurate? I'd like to avoid creating a custom version of the provided people picker view.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this conclusion accurate?

Not where iOS is concerned. ABPeoplePickerNavigationController on iOS is a way of picking a person from the user's Contacts database. There is no "custom source".

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I am not developing on IOS but in my search thought I'd seen and "AddressBookRef" like member that allowed a custom contact source. Any rate, I am interested in doing so on OS X. Thanks again for the response.

Comment: Right, but what I'm implying is, I don't think that's what this is for on either platform. On iOS at least, if you instantiate an AddressBookRef, it *is* the user's Contacts database, automatically. I would expect it to be the same on Mac OS X.

Comment: Yeah, you are likely correct. What I saw may have simply been referring to a custom i.e., filtered view on the same address book database and not an outright different source.